# React-native iOS build error after link command

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, mobile, fonts

I got the following error when I try to run the app. I noticed that this error happens after run 'npx react-native link'.

```sh
    Command line invocation:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme MyApp -destination id=ED360224-1DF7-481F-BCE5-9700938E4533

note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/vidolin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gbsfowkzxjogwsdruwnezgcjnqvv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/Zocial.ttf':

Target 'MyApp' (project 'MyApp') has copy command from '/Users/vidolin/development/MyApp/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/Zocial.ttf' to '/Users/vidolin/Library/D

Command line invocation:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme MyApp -destination id=ED360224-1DF7-481F-BCE5-9700938E4533

note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/vidolin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gbsfowkzxjogwsdruwnezgcjnqvv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/Zocial.ttf':

Target 'MyApp' (project 'MyApp') has copy command from '/Users/vidolin/development/MyApp/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/Zocial.ttf' to '/Users/vidolin/Library/D
```

Can anyone help me, pls?

Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not need to run **npx react-native link** anymore just run **pod install** at ios folder. Then go back to the root folder and run **yarn ios** to apply the changes.